# How to Encrypt a Django Project inorder to deliver to a customer without seeing the code inside

Tags: python-3.x, django, shell, unix, encryption

I have a project which is a web application which is using Django framework which contains python and shell scripts in it.
I wanted to Encrypt the package, so that the customers couldn't read/write what's there inside.
Is there a way to encrypt the packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I encrypt my django code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046621/how-can-i-encrypt-my-django-code)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot succeed via encryption or obfuscation etc.. Depending on your clients, a simple contract, and maybe some really basic checks will go a long much further than some complicated decryption system.

It's like hiding your URL on your website so hacker won't find it ... with very simple tool this break, same goes for you.

You might try to ship it as .pyc (Python compiled byte-code), but again... simple for them to reverse it.