# Protecting or Licensing a Django Application

Tags: python, django, security

I am making a Django application and I am running into an issue. I know Python is interpreted and it would be impossible to completely fight against piracy, however I want to implement some sort of security/licensing feature for my application.

I thought I would post the question because I can't find much information about this online. I'm not sure if I should create some sort of installer which downloads files from a server depending on if a key is valid or not and installs them onto a users host, or if I should encrypt the files upon sending and decrypt them with a key.

If anybody has any pointers or if anybody has faced this before I'd love to hear!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I package and sell a Django app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164901/how-would-i-package-and-sell-a-django-app)

Comment: Okay then.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is very late. but I have implemented license validation through python java bridge. I am generating tokens at the device level. and put a valid key according to that token so that it doesn't work on another device. and I have disabled the main feature for an invalid license key. and also compiled source code in deployment. however, it is not difficult to decompile code but at least we can prevent a normal user.